# Extending maps to disc homeomorphisms isotopic to the identity

Tags: gn.general-topology, manifolds

Consider the closed unit disc $\mathbb D^n$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and its closed subdisc $D$ centered at the origin with radius $1/2$. Denote by $V$ the interior of $\mathbb D^n$. I wonder whether the following statement is true:

Given a continuous injective map $f\colon D\to V$ sufficiently close to the identity, there is a homeomorphism $h\colon\mathbb D^n\to\mathbb D^n$ which extends $f$ and which is isotopic to the identity.

If this is true then it is probably a (more or less) straightforward corollary of some known topological result. I would appreciate any relevant reference.

Comment: Not at all, once $n\ge 3$ (because of existence of wild spheres, which are tame on one side).